# Hi, I'm using Jquery DataTable to paginate table records, how can I fetch 50-100 records at a time and paginate them with 10 records in each page

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I need to fectch 50-100 records at a time from server and paginate with 10 record in each page, so that when I goto 2nd page, it should show existing record, not fetch from server. Since I need to select/check bulk of records at time and submit it.

the html table is:

```
<form id="frm-example" action="/path/to/your/script" method="POST">
       <table id="example">
            <thead> 
              <th ><input type="checkbox" id="select-all"></th>
              <th class="head2" >Txn ID</th>
              <th class="head2">Member ID</th>
              <th class="head2">Name</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            </tbody>
          </table>

<p>Press <b>Submit</b> and check console for URL-encoded form data that would be submitted.</p>
<p><button>Submit</button></p>
</form>
```

Hers's my working code of jquery Datatable, which fetches 10 records at a time, but I need to select 150 or more records by clicking select all checkbox, and I want to paginate those 150+ reocrds with ten each page.

```
$(document).ready(function (){ 
     var data = {
      'org_id' : <?php echo $org_id ?>,
    };  
   var table = $('#example').DataTable({
      'serverMethod': 'post',
    'ajax': {
          'url':'<?php echo base_url()?>Supervisor_cntrl/get_Testing_Table_data',
          'data' : data,
      },
      'columnDefs': [{
         'targets': 0,
         'searchable':false,
         'orderable':false,
         'className': 'dt-body-center',
         'render': function (data, type, full, meta){
             return '<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="' 
                + $('<div/>').text(data).html() + '">';
         }
      },
      { data: 'transaction_id' },
      { data: 'member_id'},
      { data: 'member_fullname' },
      'order': [1, 'asc']
   });


   //"Select all"
   $('#select-all').on('click', function(){
      var rows = table.rows({ 'search': 'applied' }).nodes();
      $('input[type="checkbox"]', rows).prop('checked', this.checked);
   });

   $('#example tbody').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(){
      if(!this.checked){
         var el = $('#example-select-all').get(0);
         if(el && el.checked && ('indeterminate' in el)){
            el.indeterminate = true;
         }
      }
   });

   });
});
</script>
```

Heres my server-side code in PHP codeignitor. In this code, for privacy i'm masking the actual query with characters "xzyxzyxzyxzy........".

Variables like $draw, $row.. till $searchValue are posted default by the dataTable plugin itself.

```
public function get_Testing_Table_data()
{
  $org_id=$this->input->post('org_id');

  $draw = $_POST['draw'];
  $row = $_POST['start'];
  $rowperpage = $_POST['length']; // Rows display per page
  $columnIndex = $_POST['order'][0]['column']; // Column index
  $columnName = $_POST['columns'][$columnIndex]['data']; // Column name
  $columnSortOrder = $_POST['order'][0]['dir']; // asc or desc
  $searchValue = $_POST['search']['value']; // Search value
  ## Search 
  $searchQuery = " ";
  if($searchValue != ''){ 
  $searchQuery = "( t.transaction_id like '%".$searchValue."%' or md.member_fullname like '%".$searchValue."%') and ";
  }

  ## Total number of records without filtering
  $sel = "SELECT count(*) as allcount,xzyxzyxzyxzy........ where t.org_id = '$org_id' ";
  $records1 = $this->db->query($sel);
  $records = $records1->row_array();
  $totalRecords = $records['allcount'];

  ## Total number of record with filtering
  $sel="SELECT  count(*) as allcount,xxxxxxxxxx........ where  $searchQuery t.org_id = '$org_id' ";
  $records1 = $this->db->query($sel);
  $records = $records1->row_array();
  $totalRecordwithFilter = $records['allcount'];

  ## Fetch records
  
  $empQuery ="SELECT xzyxzyxzyxzy........ where  $searchQuery t.org_id = '$org_id' ORDER BY ".$columnName." ".$columnSortOrder."  LIMIT $row,$rowperpage";

  $empRecords = $this->db->query($empQuery);

  $data = array();
  foreach($empRecords->result() as $row) {
    $data[] = array(
        $row->transaction_id,
        $row->transaction_id,
        $row->member_id,
        $row->member_fullname,
    );
  }

  ## Response
  $response = array(
  "data" => $data,
  "draw" => intval($draw),
  "iTotalRecords" => $totalRecords,
  "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $totalRecordwithFilter,
  );
  echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: Please do let me know if the question needs further explanation!

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to reduce the load on your server...? I also think it's an interesting problem, but one that is likely too large for a simple answer. I think that rather than thinking of your server as the source of the data, I'd initialize an array on page load and populate it with 150 records from your server... once the user has passed the 15th page you'll likely need the server for more records... it's an odd one though. Especially as the total number of records will change after each hit on the server.

Comment: Hi!..I want to select the desired rows by checking the checkboxs in the first column, and submit it to the server for further operations on those checked records in DB. currently this implementation of jquery Datatable fetches only 10 records every time, but my I want to browse through 50-100 records and check them and submit. But when i click next button it refreshes the table! with new ten records.

Comment: after 15th page,how can I trigger ajax in dataTable? set the respective values? and can I append newly fetched data?

Comment: Instead of 10 records, I need 50 records at time, paginated as 10 in each page. once i reach 5th page, 6th to 10th must load.